# Show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$ given by:

$ \ \ \ \ \ \  \mu(A) := $ the number of rationals in $A$ (or $\infty$ if that is the case).

I'm asked to show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. In other words, that I can write $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup\limits_{i\ge 1} A_i$, where $A_i \in \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$ and $\mu (A_i) < \infty$.

##### My attempt

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Define $B^*(q, \epsilon) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \cap (q-\epsilon, q + \epsilon)\ | \ x \not\in \mathbb{Q} / \{q\} \}$. In other words, $B^*(q, \epsilon)$ is an open interval minus all rationals except $q$ in it. Then, if $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, we get that $\mu(B^*(q,\epsilon)) = 1$. And since $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup\limits_{q\in \mathbb{Q}}{B^*(q, \epsilon)}$, it follows that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

But I can't prove to myself that $B^*(q,\epsilon) \in \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}})$. Is it? How would you solve this?

Comment: Take a Borel set and remove a point. Is it Borel?

Comment: You could also take $A_0=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $A_i=\{q_i\}$, where $q_i$ is an enumeration of the rationals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $B^*(q, \epsilon) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Indeed,
$$B^*(q,\epsilon) = (q-\epsilon, q + \epsilon)\cap F^c$$
where $F\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Then note that a subset of rationals is necessarily Borel measurable because it is a countable union of singeltons (which are closed, so Borel).

Answer (score 1):

Singletons are closed hence are Borel-measurable.

Then $\mathbb Q$ is Borel-measurable as countable union of singletons.

Then $A\cap\mathbb Q^c$ is Borel-measurable whenever $A$ is Borel-measurable.

I hope this is enough to convince that the sets you mention are indeed Borel-measurable.